# How to fit integer output in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I have a data set that contains 104 input features and 96 output values ​​to be predicted, the input features are floating values ​​normalized to [-1,1], and **each out put value would be one integer among [-1,0,1]**.

I am basically new to data science and machine learning, and I need to know **what kind of neural network model would fit best for this kind of data**. I have googled this for a quite long time, can you guys help me ? Thank you!

我的每一条训练数据具有104个[-1,1]之间的浮点型输入量和96个整数型输出量，每个输出值为[-1,0,1]之中的一个整数。
我是机器学习的新手，我想知道**应该采用何种神经网络模型来解决此问题**，在post本问题之前我已经自行搜索了很久，希望大家能给我一些帮助，谢谢！

Answer (score 1):

You may check a multitarget model like [this one](https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_multitarget_functionalAPI.py). Basically Keras‘ [functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/) gives you a lot of flexibility to model multitarget problems.

You have three classes per target, so make sure you use `'categorical_crossentropy'` as loss function with three terminal layers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check the link you posted and learn more about the **"multitarget model"**, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the output range is just three integers (-1, 0 and 1), the problem would probably be best approached as multinomial classification. For a start, you can look up a few multinomial classification tutorials for `scikit-learn` for Python: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check the link you posted and learn more about **"multinomial classification"**, thank you!